# iOS 14.5 App Tracking Transparency for firebase logs in react-native app

Tags: firebase, react-native, react-native-ios, ios14

Firebase logs stopped working as soon as updated to `iOS 14.5` for one of the `react-native` app I am working on.

What are the necessary changes that we need to do to make it working again?

Comment: I can't even run my RN app after I upgraded Xcode and iOS to 14.5. I'll keep checking this thread because I'll probably face the same issues as you are.

Comment: @GuilhermeCrozariol - What issues you are facing?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to request Tracking permissions first (I used react-native-permissions):

```js
import { request, RESULTS, PERMISSIONS } from 'react-native-permissions'
import { Settings } from 'react-native-fbsdk-next'

export const requestPermissionTransparency = async () => {
  return await request(PERMISSIONS.IOS.APP_TRACKING_TRANSPARENCY)
}

useEffect(() => {
    ;(async () => {
      const result = await requestPermissionTransparency()
      if (result === RESULTS.GRANTED) {
        await firebase.analytics().setAnalyticsCollectionEnabled(true)
        await Settings.setAdvertiserTrackingEnabled(true)
      } else {
        await firebase.analytics().setAnalyticsCollectionEnabled(false)
        await Settings.setAdvertiserTrackingEnabled(false)
      }
    })()
  }, [])
```

Remember to add this file in the root project:

```json
// <project-root>/firebase.json
{
  "react-native": {
    "analytics_auto_collection_enabled": false
  }
}
```

References: https://rnfirebase.io/analytics/usage

Comment: Do you need to manually call Settings.initializeSDK() after 'GRANTED' or just initialize it in AppDelegate? ([FBSDKApplicationDelegate initializeSDK:launchOptions])

Comment: I think you only need to set setAdvertiserTrackingEnabled to true and it is initialized automatically (see doc):
(https://developers.facebook.com/docs/audience-network/setting-up/platform-setup/ios/advertising-tracking-enabled/)